# How to validate using regex in python for case below

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as `"test string {{#}}, {{#}} , #<any text>"`

I need to replace only # which comes before text(third one) and not the one in curly braces ?

Expected output should be
`"test string {{#}}, {{#}} , <any text>"`

here the third # is getting replaced by "" (empty string)

Iam new at regex any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would a negative lookahead suffice?

Comment: I looking for it now . not sure what exactly it is . Thanks

Comment: [`#(?!})`](https://regex101.com/r/h5m9Y4/1) would mean you don't want to match the hash if it's followed by a closing curly bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s =  "test string {{#}}, {{#}} , #<any text>"

# with replace

print(s.replace('#<', '<'))

test string {{#}}, {{#}} , <any text>

# with regex, where (?=<) is a look ahead

print(re.sub(r'#(?=<)','',s))

test string {{#}}, {{#}} , <any text>
```